# Format Macbook 2, 1 running 10.4.1

Tags: macos, disk-format

I bought a MacBook 2, 1 at a market day and the user didn't wipe the computer.  I was wondering how to format it to basically start fresh. I’ve  tried booting to recovery mode and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>doesn't seem to work.  I also tried the 
advice from the following thread and it didnt seem to work either:

[Clean wipe iMac running 10.4.11 OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244408/clean-wipe-imac-running-10-4-11-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

In order to “wipe” the drive and reinstall, you need the original install disks.   The Early 2008 (White) MacBook did not support internet recovery at all.

Also, the highest supported OS is 10.7.5 (Lion) so if you intend to upgrade, keep this in mind.  These install DVDs are available on the secondary market (eBay).